# sql query help (count)

Tags: sql, h2, jooq

I have 3 tables

```
CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMER_ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, ... other fields)
LICENSES(LICENSE_ID, CREATED_AT, RELEASE_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, ... other fields)
RELEASES(RELEASE_ID, RELEASE_NAME, RELEASE_NUMBER, ... other fields)
```

CREATED_AT in LICENSE is a DATE (NOT NULL) field.

the tables are related according to primary key/foreign key with the same name; a customer can have 0 or more licenses and every license has a release.

I would like to get from these tables:

the customer's firstname, lastname and the release_id of the last license that was created (according to CREATED_AT field in LICENSE to find the last one ) if there is one.

for this one i used this query:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.FIRSTNAME,
       CUSTOMERS.LASTNAME,

  (SELECT RELEASES.RELEASE_ID
   FROM RELEASES
   INNER JOIN LICENSES ON LICENSES.RELEASE_ID = RELEASES.RELEASE_ID
   INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS AS t ON t.CUSTOMER_ID = LICENSES.CUSTOMER_ID
   WHERE t.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
   ORDER BY LICENSES.CREATED_AT DESC LIMIT 1) AS REL_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM RELEASES
     INNER JOIN LICENSES ON LICENSES.RELEASE_ID = RELEASES.RELEASE_ID
     INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS AS t ON LICENSES.CUSTOMER_ID = t.CUSTOMER_ID
     AND t.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

It seems to work but I ask if someone can confirm me this or if it is possible to make it simpler.

The other data I want to get from these tables are `RELEASES.RELEASE_ID, RELEASES.RELEASE_NAME, RELEASES.RELEASE_NUMBER` and the count of customers who last license(according to CREATED_AT in LICENSES) has this release.

I was not able to create this query.
I am using h2 database.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be equivalent

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.FIRSTNAME,
       CUSTOMERS.LASTNAME,
      (SELECT LICENSES.RELEASE_ID
       FROM LICENSES
       WHERE LICENSES.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
       ORDER BY LICENSES.CREATED_AT DESC
       LIMIT 1) AS REL_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM LICENSES
    WHERE LICENSES.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID
)
```

You don't need to join all those tables if you have foreign key constraints on `LICENSES.RELEASE_ID` and `LICENSES.CUSTOMER_ID`. In particular, there's no point in joining the `RELEASES` table, because the `LICENSES.RELEASE_ID` column already contains the wanted information.

#### LATERAL / CROSS APPLY join in other databases

For completeness' sake, if this were PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc., you could perform a [lateral join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL), which is also known as [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.FIRSTNAME,
       CUSTOMERS.LASTNAME,
       l.RELEASE_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM LICENSES
    WHERE LICENSES.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
    ORDER BY LICENSES.CREATED_AT DESC
    LIMIT 1
) l
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and the advices. My question consists in 2 queries, the other one is in the last part of the question and I was not able to create it. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: @res1: Please ask a new question here on Stack Overflow. It will be much easier for future visitors to understand what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME, r.RELEASE_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS c
INNER JOIN LICENSES l ON (c.CUSTOMER_ID = l.CUSTOMER_ID)
INNER JOIN RELEASES r ON (r.RELEASE_ID = l.RELEASE_ID)

WHERE r.CREATED_AT = ( SELECT MAX(t.CREATED_AT) FROM RELEASES t
                       WHERE t.RELEASE_ID = r.RELEASE_ID )
```

because of the inner join, only customers with releases will be listed.

Comment: The `RELEASES` table isn't really needed here. Besides, the `RELEASE_ID` (with the most recent `LICENSES.CREATED_AT` date) is missing from the result set

Comment: You are right, I've not noticed that Column. I've updated the query above

Comment: thanks for the answer, as i said in the comments to Lukas's answer, my question consists in 2 queries, I was not able to create the last one